# Safely capture URL Encoded String for Search Input?

Tags: php, drupal

I basically have a search form with input:

```
<input type="text" name="search" />
```

This ends up sending the user off to:

```
/search/[URL_ENCODED_STRING]
```

So if they searched for

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

The url would be:

```
/search/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.stackoverflow.com%252F
```

My problem comes with knowing if the input I then read later is safe. I would then on the search page use Drupal's inherent ways of reading the value (arg(1)). But even without drupal, the result would be essential the same. I would end up with:

```
$variable = urldecode($input);
```

If I then print out $variable, it will show:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

My question is, what kind of sanitizing must I apply to this string before using it in SQL? Is it simply "addslashes"? Or should I remove all non alphanumeric and number values?

**NOTE**

I haven't gotten to that part yet, but I'm fairly certain Drupal will apply it's own sanitization if I pass this variable to the built-in search function, but I still would like to know what the right way is to sanitize this input to avoid malicious users doing strange things on the website.

**UPDATE**

I got to the part and Drupal does take care of the prepared statement part. But I still don't know how I would sanitize the string when printing it here:

```
<div id="searchedFor">
    <span class="preLabel">You searched for</span>
    <h2><?php print $_REQUEST['search']; ?></h2>
</div>
```

What is the most correct way to print that out?

Comment: If you use prepared statements with binding of key/value pairs, your sql should be safe.

Comment: I managed to get passed the prepared statements part. But still hit a stumbling block. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sanitize to the page, use `htmlentities()` or `strip_tags()` or `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
<div id="searchedFor">
    <span class="preLabel">You searched for</span>
    <h2><?php echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['search'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></h2>
</div>
```

**Example:**

```
<?php echo htmlentities("<script>NastyJS('code');</script>", ENT_QUOTES); ?>
<!-- Shows in browser this way -->
<script>NastyJS('code');</script>
<!-- but shows in source this way -->
&lt;script&gt;NastyJS(&#039;code&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

Comment: Yes because it converts all the HTML tags so malicious code can not be embedded and executed. If you use `strip_tags()`, it will only output plain text, no HTML at all.